# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout section clipping

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm making an `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` with `orthogonalScrollingBehavior` sections.

I would like to clip them section based so that I can have different insets for clipping, or at best clip them at the `NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem` level but can't find a way to achieve this.

The main goal I'm trying to get is to have a full width header as `NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem` and section that has small inset for which it is clipping.

Right now, either I clip everything or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Till now the only solution I found was to embed child collections inside cells, which can clip their own content therefore, allowing to scroll horizontally and prevent cells from rendering above the borders.